# ViewPager ListView

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have changed my previous question to this. I have found a [Sample](http://spacetech.dk/android-viewpager-with-listview-pages.html) of ListView ViewPager but my problem is the sample adds ListView programmatically what I want is already set in my xml.

Code from [Sample](http://spacetech.dk/android-viewpager-with-listview-pages.html):

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listview1 = new ListView(mContext);
    ListView listview2 = new ListView(mContext);
    ListView listview3 = new ListView(mContext);

    Vector<View> pages = new Vector<View>();

    pages.add(listview1);
    pages.add(listview2);
    pages.add(listview3);

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    CustomerPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomerPagerAdapter(mContext, pages);
    vp.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "A1", "B1",
                    "C1", "D1" }));
    listview2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "A2", "B2",
                    "C2", "D2" }));
    listview3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "A3", "B3",
                    "C3", "D3" }));

}
 }
```

CustomerPagerAdapter:

```
public class CustomerPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private Vector<View> pages;

public CustomerPagerAdapter(Context context, Vector<View> pages) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.pages = pages;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View page = pages.get(position);
    container.addView(page);
    return page;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pages.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

 }
```

activity_main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**How to Set ListView in XML using this codes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to stick with Flipper until I find a perfectly working Circular ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using Intent for this? Same as you call one activity from another.

Comment: I have not yet. I will try. Thanks for the idea